# Call controller action from non controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to invoke a controller action from a regular C# class, that is not a controller?

All I found so far uses redirectToAction, but this is controller exclusive.

Comment: can't you simple call function by creating instance and call using the same instance?

Comment: What you are probably doing is keeping business logic code in your controller instead of separating it out. I suggest you don't do this and move the code you are using to a location where it can be used properly.

Comment: You mean, create an instance of the controller and call the method from that instance?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you asking about accessing a controller class from another class in the same project/solution? or Are you asking about how to call a method in your controller from a completely different application, which may not have a valid login to your web application/controller?

Comment: @chiapa Yes I meant to be that but then your architecture would suffer bad coding practices. suggestion while posting question here put the possible minimal entire scenario here so that people surfing here would contribute their great idea towards the best practices.

Comment: @KosalaW, the idea is to call a controller method from a class that's not a controller, belonging to a different project but on the same solution

Comment: @chiapa : It's anti-pattern to call controller methods that way. If you want to reuse what's in the controller, your best option is move that functionality to a separate class. Then you can use it in your controller or wherever you want.

Comment: @KosalaW, I know that, you are absolutely right. But that doesn't answer my question though!

Comment: Best way can be to move everything from the controller method to the business layer class, and use that as and when required, instead of calling controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller is a class like any other, which means you can do this:

`var homeController = new HomeController();`

(assuming you have your project references setup, I'm not including namespaces in my example, as I don't know what yours are)

Thus you can then execute the methods of that controller via the `homeController` variable. But, as has been pointed out in the comments, this is not a good design at all. I would strongly recommend you don't do this.

A controller should be called from other controllers, or web requests.

Comment: This would make the controller lack meta data like (`Server.MapPath`)